# Can you use "cynicism" in the same way as "witticism"?

Tags: grammar

The word "witticism" can be used to refer to a specific witty statement. You could refer to such a statement as "a witticism".

But the word "cynicism" seems to be used differently. [For example](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cynical),

> H.L. Mencken was famous for saying cynical things like, "Nobody ever
>   went broke underestimating the intelligence of the American public."

While clearly that sentiment is exhibiting *cynicism*, could I also describe that particular quote as "*a cynicism*"?  Following the pattern of "witticism" this seems like it should be acceptable grammar, except that I'm not familiar with the word actually being used like that.

While the suffixes of these two words are obviously the same actually the reason I was thinking of this is how they are both used to describe the content of statements or communication. It just seemed reasonable that they could be used in the same parts of speech.

Comment: Using "cynicism" as you propose is not at all idiomatic.  You could get away with it in some contexts, but I wouldn't recommend it for your master's thesis.

Answer (score 1):

"Witticism" is a fossilized play on words that comes from John Dryden--a portmanteau of "wit" and "criticism." So "criticism" is the relevant comparison.

"Criticism" can be either a count noun or a mass noun, but "witticism" seems to have been born and remained a count noun.

Then, "witticism" is and can be a count noun just because "criticism" can be a count noun, and it seems "criticism" is a count noun (in normal usage) just in being a nominalization of the verb "criticize." That is, in normal usage it counts singular instances of criticizing. On the other hand, "cynicism" nominalizes a state or property. There's no grammatical problem with counting cynicisms, but it would be a heroically abstract pursuit. No doubt some or other continental theorist talks about "cynicisms" but normal people don't count them.

It seems like the two words just don't have anything in common besides the "-ism" suffix. Edit: "Cynicism" doesn't have an analogous verb form.

Answer (score 0):

Cynicism is a category.  Witticism is both a category and a rhetorical device.  You say Mencken's epigram is witticism/wit (category) or "a witticism" (rhetorical device).  Since cynicism is a category only, Mencken's epigram is cynicism, but saying Mencken's epigram is "a cynicism" makes no sense.

Comment: It doesn't make *no* sense: one can still see what was meant. But no, it's certainly not correct usage.